# "sql: no rows in result set"

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

I am handling user auth data posted to my Go backend through an HTML form. I am building on [some boilerplate](https://github.com/Massad/gin-boilerplate/blob/master/README.md) to learn Go better.

My problem is what the following `func` returns:

```
func (ctrl UserController) Signin(c *gin.Context) {

  var signinForm forms.SigninForm
  user, err := userModel.Signin(signinForm)

  if err := c.ShouldBindWith(&signinForm, binding.Form); err != nil {
      c.JSON(406, gin.H{"message": "Invalid signin form", "form": signinForm})
      c.Abort()
      return
  }

    if err == nil {
        session := sessions.Default(c)
        session.Set("user_id", user.ID)
        session.Set("user_email", user.Email)
        session.Set("user_name", user.Name)
        session.Save()

        c.JSON(200, gin.H{"message": "User signed in", "user": user})
    } else {
        c.JSON(406, gin.H{"message": "Invalid signin details", "error": err.Error()})
    }

}
```

The first `if` statement validates the input, and that works fine (error if the email isn't in proper email format, no error if it is). However, if input is properly validated, the `else` clause of the second statement is triggered, and the following JSON is returned:

```
{
error: "sql: no rows in result set",
message: "Invalid signin details"
}
```

It is probably useful to also post the relevant code in my `User` model:

```
//User ...
type User struct {
    ID        int    `db:"id, primarykey, autoincrement" json:"id"`
    Email     string `db:"email" json:"email"`
    Password  string `db:"password" json:"-"`
    Name      string `db:"name" json:"name"`
    UpdatedAt int64  `db:"updated_at" json:"updated_at"`
    CreatedAt int64  `db:"created_at" json:"created_at"`
}

//UserModel ...
type UserModel struct{}

//Signin ...
func (m UserModel) Signin(form forms.SigninForm) (user User, err error) {

    err = db.GetDB().SelectOne(&user, "SELECT id, email, password, name, updated_at, created_at FROM public.user WHERE email=LOWER($1) LIMIT 1", form.Email)

    if err != nil {
        return user, err
    }

    bytePassword := []byte(form.Password)
    byteHashedPassword := []byte(user.Password)

    err = bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword(byteHashedPassword, bytePassword)

    if err != nil {
        return user, errors.New("Invalid password")
    }

    return user, nil
}
```

How do I resolve the `sql: no rows in result set` error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the order of operations in your code.
At first you need to get data from request with `if err := c.ShouldBindWith(&signinForm, binding.Form); err != nil {` and after that you need to try get data from database with `user, err := userModel.Signin(signinForm)`

Comment: I still get the same error. `f err := c.ShouldBindWith(&signinForm, binding.Form); err != nil {` shouldn't effect this issue, as it is merely validating the form.

I haven't written the user signup route yet, so there is currently nothing in the database. Would that be causing this error, perhaps?

Comment: @223seneca Pavlo's answer is correct, your ordering is just wrong, it would never work even if you had rows in your database because without setting the request's data to the `singinForm` value, which is done by the binding mechanism, you would always be passing an empty `form.Email` to the query and an empty `form.Password` to the bcrypt's compare function.

Comment: @mkopriva Regarding your comment about the error `sql: no rows in result set`, I was unsure given the fact that I find that behavior strange (it's odd that it throws an error, as the possibility that there just aren't any users yet doesn't seem error-worthy). I can do without the condescension though, thanks.

Comment: @223seneca and regardless of whether your order would work or not you should be very careful about passing unvalidated data to your database.

Comment: Good point. I'm super new to Go so I'm likely to miss such subtleties in the drive to simply get my code working.

Comment: @223seneca the db and the db driver doesn't know or care what the tables represent in your app, whether no-row is ok or not that's not their business. If your signin functionality should continue working if no user with given email exists, then your `UserModel.Signin` should check specifically for the `sql.ErrNoRows` value and return nil or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

There are good reasons for this. Ideally it tries to read paths by the separator, meaning `/path/abcd/` and `/path/abcd` are different. `abcd` IS the resource in the latter while the resource lies somewhere within `abcd` in the former. With that in mind, then it will not be able to route properly to `/path/abcd` if you also have a path `/path` as well. In order to remove that ambiguity as to which handler to use, you need to mention the handler for the more specific path ie, `/path/abcd` before the more generic one `/path`.